# Que función cumple onDetach() y onAttach() en un fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Al crear fragmentes y visualizar estas funciones me doy cuenta que puedo quitarlas y no afecta el funcionamiento del fragment. Pero que puedo hacer en estas dos funciones ?

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola casi no uso esas funciones pero he leído que estas son parte del ciclo de vida de un `Fragment`, tal como `onCreate()`:

`onAttach()`: Es el ciclo de cuando el fragmento ha sido adjuntado a la Actividad

`onDetach()`: Es el ciclo de vida de cuando el fragmento es removido o quitado de la actividad y ya no esta disponible.

Si gustas un poco de lectura te recomiendo le des una vuelta a este [Link](http://gpmess.com/blog/2014/04/16/buenas-practicas-usando-fragments-en-android/)

Comment: Gracias, espero que alguien le sirva, igual.